# MySQL cant find my table?

Tags: mysql

I reformatted my C drive, reinstall mysql for windows then deleted my 2 log files + ibdata1. I set the data path in my config file and was able to connect to my database. I see all my databases however if i try to select any data i get an error

I remembered I needed to set files per table so i wrote

```
innodb_file_per_table
```

I restarted mysqld and I still get an error. This is what i get specifically. t is the name of my database (its a test database). I see all the databases i have with `show databases`. `show tables;` works as well. But I can't select anything or `desc TABLE`. My database are 60gb in total so i'm worried i broke it all.

```
mysql> select * from inc;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 't.inc' doesn't exist
```

Comment: You should have made a backup.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the fresh my.ini file no longer had the `innodb_data_home_dir="c:/path/to"`. I looked at my ini file from a external HD for a different database. I must have a different version of the installer/mysql (even though its still 5.5)

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the data when you deleted **ibdata1** file.

Comment: I guess but thats what the documentation told me to do. I did have a backup. I figured it out and posted my answer